# casting void* to struct

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers

I know that somehow similar question was asked but I couldn't figure out the answer from it. 
Now I have some specific sturcts and one generic struct with '''void*''' the problem is depending on given parameter in a function I should cast this generic pointer to pointer to struct, when I try to access members in struct compiler doesn't accept this

**I want to return `struct gen` cointaing the data of `struct a` or `struct b`**

example code

```
typedef enum
{
    chooseA = 0,
    chooseB = 1,

} chooseVal;

typedef struct
{
    uint16_t x1;
    uint8_t  x2;
    uint8_t* x3;
} a;

typedef struct
{
    uint16_t y1;
    uint8_t  y2;
    uint8_t* y33;
} b;

typedef struct
{
    chooseVal z;
    void* object;
} gen;

void readStruct(gen* out, uint16_t val, uint16_t X1)
{
    out->z==val;
    if(out->z==chooseA)
    {
        a* A;
        A=(a*)out->object;
        out->object->x1 = X1;/*This is the not working line */
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `A->x1`?

Comment: I would also recommend that you use a `union` of `a` and `b` (or possibly of `a*` and `b*`) instead of `void*`. Then you don't need temporary variables and won't have casting problems.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I want to return `gen->object` with the data of `a` or `b`

Comment: You can use `A->x1`. If you really need to avoid defining a local pointer variable of the correct type, you can use `((a*)out->object)->x1 = X1;`.

Comment: The cast from `void *` to any other type of pointer is not necessary in C.  If your compiler is complaining, it's not a conforming C compiler.

Comment: There is no member of the `gen` struct type called `chooseVal`, so `out->chooseVal` is wrong. Perhaps you meant `out->z`? Also, the expression statement `out->chooseVal==val;` doesn't do anything as nothing is done with the result of the comparison.

Comment: Post the error message from the compiler in the answer

Comment: ...Or in the question.

Comment: The code in the question suggests that you think executing `A=(a*)out->object;` will change `out->object` so that it can be used in `out-object->x1`. it does not. The `A=` is an assignment that changes the value of `A`. Otherwise, these are just expressions that are evaluated—they produce values; they do not change things. `out->object` takes the **value** of the pointer in `out->object` and `(a*)` converts that value to a pointer to an `a`, but it does not change either the value or the type stored in `out->object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific problem is caused by you still accessing the void pointer instead of the struct pointer `A`. The whole reason why you created `A` must be for this purpose, so simply do `A->x1 = X1;`.

However, this is needlessly complicated. Since both structs have indentical members and just different variable names, this is a perfect case for a `union`, which means that the struct members could be allocated together with the enum instead of somewhere else. With standard C you can do this:

```
typedef enum { A, B } choose_val_t;

typedef union
{
  struct
  {
    uint16_t x1;
    uint8_t  x2;
    uint8_t* x3;
  };
  struct
  {
    uint16_t y1;
    uint8_t  y2;
    uint8_t* y3;
  };
} ab_t;

typedef struct
{
  choose_val_t val;
  ab_t ab;
} gen_t;

void readStruct(gen_t* out, choose_val_t val, uint16_t X1)
{
  out->val = val;
  switch(val)
  {
    case A: out->ab.x1 = X1; return ;
    case B: /* something */  return ;
  }
}
```